# Where Zend Framework config file?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am learning Zend Framework 1 and face with two types of config files

in one app structure it was

'application/config.ini'

but in another one there was 'application/configs/application.ini'

Why that? Or this are different files?

Can somebody explain me what for one and another file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZF1 apps by convention use `application/configs/application.ini` for app configuration. I have no idea what `application/config.ini` is - it could be something specific to that particular tutorial (or possibly something from earlier versions).

[ZF1 reaches end of life in September](https://framework.zend.com/blog/2016-06-28-zf1-eol.html). If you want to learn Zend Framework, you should learn the current version (ZF3).

Comment: Yeah, mb it was something specific for one project what i saw. Unfortunately I must working with existing project which has version 1.x
Sure, for new project it will be version 3 or at least 2. Thanks.